# HP G6 laptop does not start Audio Service, leads to very bad sound

Tags: windows-7, audio

I have an HP G6 laptop, with "Altec Lansing SRS Premium Sound".

Every time I restart my computer, it starts with the audio service not started.  Audio Service apparently is in charge of swapping from speaker to the headphone jack. Well, *that* works without the service.

But apparently, it also turns the quality up.  I kid you not, when this Audio Service is off, and I plug in my headphones, they sound just as bad as the speakers. Think AM radio... but as I start the service, the quality is back!

So, first off, any idea why this service wouldn't be starting even though it's set as automatic?

Secondly, do you think there's something actually forcing the PC speakers to be this crappy?  Any hope to get those any better?  They are seriously bad, and I'm wondering if this has something to do with it.

Comment: Sounds like an issue with the manufacturer. Have you tried to contact them?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried removing the existing audio driver and utility software, downloading an updated version from HP (or the audio manufacturer) and installing that?

Answer (score 0):

Try reinstaling driver first. Go to hp.com, download new one.
REMOVE old one first (with included software) and then install new driver.

- There can be a hardware error too. But in this case probably You'll have to visit some 'electric magic man' to see your mainboard...